# Error 404/resource is not available in Eclipse EE Kepler with Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, eclipse-kepler

I installed Tomcat 7 and integrated it with Eclipse EE Kepler.

I added the server through the "add new server" option under the "server" tab.

Did the necessary changes, but when I visit `localhost:8080`, it gives me the Tomcat welcome page; when I create a Dynamic Web Project and try to run any file in that project, or the project itself, it gives `Error 404/Resource not available` even though the server is running fine.

Answer (score 3):

Is the context root setting for the project included in your URL? By default, the context root is usually set to the project name (which may not be what you expect).

You can change the context root by opening the project settings, selecting "Web Project Settings", and adjusting the context root to suit your needs:

[image: screenshot of eclipse project settings dialog]

Whatever you use, it must match the context root used in your URL:

[image: screenshot of example URL]

To set the context root to ROOT, just use "/".

You can also change the context root on the server's "Web Modules" properties page. Open the "Servers" view (the same view used to stop and start the server) and double-click the server with your web app. Click the "Modules" tab (in the lower-left corner), then locate your application in the list. You can change your deployment path after clicking the "Edit..." button.

[image: Screenshot of the eclipse modules properties page]

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if it can help but i had the same issues, the thing is eclipse keppler is not on point yet doesnt get along with tomcat 7 in my case, so i just installed Eclipse juno and integrated the same jre and it compiled the jsp right away and working fine.